# Injecting dynamically created components into dynamically created tree graph

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have to dynamically create a tree graph (the choice was for D3.js since it allows more customization, due to the fact the graph need to be customized a lot, but it's not an explicit requirement.

The graph is created just like the example for the expandable tree graph (e.g. https://observablehq.com/@d3/collapsible-tree ), the difference is I need to put a custom component as node; that component needs both do display possibly dynamic data (although that could handled by redrawing) but most importantly I need it to handle events (click on different part of the component).
With my code (provided below) the component is actually created, its template evaluated against my input, but after that I cannot find a way to actually inject it in the node.
In my code I was able to inject the HTML in the node, and it visualizes correctly in the DOM, but event handling is apparently lost this way (I guess the Angular bits are lost by these operations).
Is there a way to achieve my goal? Either an API I'm not aware of (I tried out with renderer appendChild, but it appears I cannot find a way to get the actual parent node) or another way of writing it out

Here's the only change gainst the example

```js
nodeEnter.append("foreignObject").attr("width", "100").attr("height", "100")
          .attr("dy", "0.31em")
          .attr("y", d => d._children ? -6 : 6)
          .attr("text-anchor", d => d._children ? "end" : "start")
          .html((d: d3.HierarchyNode<Graph>) => this.buildComponent(d.data))
        .clone(true).lower()
          .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
          .attr("stroke-width", 3)
          .attr("stroke", "white");
```

here's the buildComponent method:

```js
buildComponent(graph: Graph) {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PocDataComponent);
    const inputs = [
      {
      'provide': 'entity',
      'useValue': graph
      }
    ];
    const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputs), this.injector);
    const newLocal = factory.create(injector);
    newLocal.instance.entity = graph;
    newLocal.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
    return newLocal.hostView['rootNodes'][0].innerHTML;

  }
```

Graph is a simple object object containing business information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out in this article (https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-dynamic-components/) there's a not well documented API of angular for this very behavior.

Basically the trick is using applicationRef and ViewRef injects to give angular the component code to attach to the component html

basically the code can be summirized in:

```
export class ComponentBuilderService {
     constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private injector: Injector, private appRef: ApplicationRef) {}

     buildNodeComponent(graph: Graph) {
      const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PocDataComponent);
      const inputs = [
           {
             'provide': 'entity',
             'useValue': graph
           }
       ];
       const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputs), this.injector);
       const newLocal = factory.create(injector);
       newLocal.instance.entity = graph;
       newLocal.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
       this.appRef.attachView(newLocal.hostView);
       return (newLocal.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
 }
```

An important caveat though to make this works (other than declaring the components/adding to entrycomponents as needed) might be adding public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef to the constructor of your bootstraped component (i.e. AppComponent) even unused.
I wasnt able to pinpoint the actual cause, but occasionally, depending apparently on where I actually run the build component (service or another Component) it might fail without that injection (sources can be found in the article and online)